# Nested IF statement returning false, only on some cells. yet formula is the same

Tags: excel, if-statement, formulas

My formula is the same for all the cells yet some follow my IF formula while others return FALSE.

It returns the false on a few, not all, of the "Yes" responses

Formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B9),(IF(ISBLANK(C9),(IF(ISBLANK(D9),"No","Yes")))))
```

I have tried both copy/paste formula and manually typing the formula in the incorrect cells. Both return "FALSE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first and second `IF` you do not have a value if it evaluates to false. Essentially it will only say "Yes" if `B9` and `C9` is blank and `D9` is not. Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B9),(IF(ISBLANK(C9),(IF(ISBLANK(D9),"No","Yes")), "Yes")), "Yes")
```